# accessing mysql from within flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I noticed that most examples for accessing mysql from flask suggest using a plugin that calls `init_app(app)`.

I was just wondering why that is as opposed to just using a `mysql connector` somewhere in your code as you need it?

Is it that flask does better resource management with request life cycles?

Comment: You might use `init_app` if you abstract your database access through an ORM like sqlalchemy, which is better to set up once. If you use direct sql queries you can put the logic in your views, although it is not very DRY. Flask also offers some [hooks](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/reqcontext/#callbacks-and-errors) for opening and closing database connections before and after your views.

Comment: if you want to put that in an answer i'll give you credit! thanks for the info!

Answer (score 3):

Using packages like `flask-mysql` or `Flask-SQLAlchemy`, they provided useful defaults and extra helpers that make it easier to accomplish common CRUD tasks.

All of such package are good at handling relationships between objects. You only need to create the objects and then the objects contain all the functions and helpers you needed to deal with the database, you don't have to implement such code by yourself and you don't need to worry about the performance of the queries.

I had worked on a Django project（I believe the theory in Flask is similar） and its ORM is really amazing, all i need to do is writing `Models` and encapsulate business logic. All CRUD commands are handled by the built-in ORM, as a developer we don't worry about the SQL statements.

Another benefit is that it makes database migration much easier. You can switch it from MySQL to PostgresSQL with minimal code modifications which will speed up development.